# String comparison failing when using "=="?

Tags: java

I am an extreme coding noob and I've just started. I designed a rock paper scissors game and can't figure out why it won't work. For some reason the user input isn't working in the if statement. Please take a look.

```
    package com.youtube.njillatactics;

    import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

    public class RPS {
public static void main(String args[]){
    //start message
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Welcome to Nick's rock paper scissors game!");
    //get user input and convert to lower case
    String userInput = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Choose rock, paper, or scissors.").toLowerCase();
    //generate random computer input
    double computerInput = Math.random();
    //match user input to converted computer input
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, match(userInput, convert(computerInput)));
}
//convert random computer input into choice
public static String convert(double x){
    if(x < 0.33){
        return "rock";
    }else if(x < 0.66){
        return "paper";
    }else
        return "scissors";
}
//check to see who wins
public static String match(String x,String y){
    if(x == y){
        return "Tie!";
    }else
    if(x == "rock"){
        if(y == "paper"){
            return "Computer wins!";
        }else
            return "User wins!";
    } 
    if(x == "paper"){
        if(y == "scissors"){
            return "Computer wins!";
        }else
            return "User wins!";
    }
    if(x == "scissors"){
        if(y == "rock"){
            return "Computer wins!";
        }else
            return "User wins!";
    }else
        return x + ", " + y;
}
}
```

Comment: Wow. It was that simple. Like I said I'm new so thanks for helping me out. That was quick!

Comment: For future reference, it would be helpful if you took the time to identify _what_ specifically wasn't working. You didn't tell us the symptoms, much less a specific snippet of code that did one thing when you thought it would do another.

Answer (score 5):

You are comparing strings with `==` when you should be comparing them with `.equals(s)`

Instead of, for example,

```
if(y == "rock")  {
```

change it to

```
if(y.equals("rock"))
```

(You should also ensure that `y` is not `null` either by testing it, or try-catching for it.)

Comparing strings with `==` evaluates to true if the *same string object* is on both sides of the `==`.

Comparing strings with `equals(s)` compares their values, regardless if they're the same object...and obviously, if they *happen* to be the same object, it will always evaluate to `true`.

Comment: Another variation would be `if ("rock".equals(y))`

Comment: "[Yoda conditions](http://blog.codinghorror.com/new-programming-jargon)."

Comment: Even though I fully support your answer, the user might not always put exactly "rock", so you could also do y.equalsIgnoreCase("rock"); and it would make it more universal for the person playing the game

Comment: @yshavit: You think it should be the other way around, as a matter of style. I would (not so strongly) argue that `y.equals("rock")` is preferable from a "fail fast" point of view. Obviously needs to be `try`ed.

Comment: @user2277872: I'll leave it as is, but it's a good point.

Comment: @aliteralmind I wasn't trying to argue one way or another. I just like that name for the pattern. :)

Comment: I wasn't saying you SHOULD use it, I was just giving a suggestion on another approach that might have been more of a user friendly input is all :)

Comment: @user3461740: If you feel this has helped you, please consider up-voting it, and accepting it by clicking on the big green checkmark. Thank you, and best of luck!

Answer (score 1):

In java, you do not compare two strings by `x == y`. Instead, you compare by using `x.equals(y)`. This explains why those if statements do not work.